# Exercises for A/B testing/Experimental design

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references, experiment-design

I'm applying for a data scientist job, which requires a lot of knowledge in A/B testing/Experimental design. But actually I'm not very familiar with it.

For A/B testing I was recommended a great book called Trustworthy Online Controlled Experiments. but I still want to know what's your textbooks for A/B testing/Experimental design?

And is there a A/B testing case study problem set I can look into?

Comment: This question is basically asking for example interview questions. These are hard to source and the quality varies a lot. At the basic level, you can review questions around concepts (p-value, confidence intervals, t-tests, etc.). Good reviewers will ask open-ended questions based on their own recent projects. Please prove me wrong, but there just aren't good experiment questions out there to prepare for interviews.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/must-know-key-issues-problems-ab-testing.html

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/04/ab-testing-7-common-questions-answers-data-science-interviews-1.html utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+kdnuggets-data-mining-analytics+%28KDnuggets%3A+Data+Mining+and+Analytics%29&utm_content=FeedBurner

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/03/common-a-b-testing-questions-asked-during-interviews/

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/04/ab-testing-data-science-interviews.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+kdnuggets-data-mining-analytics+%28KDnuggets%3A+Data+Mining+and+Analytics%29&utm_content=FeedBurner